# Cisco AP vlan setup

Tags: cisco, dhcp, access-point

I have been racking my brain since last night and all morning with this problem...luckily it's not in a production environment yet.

I have done many searches and have come up with the same responses regarding Cisco APs and multiple SSIDs, and I think I have tried everything there is, but obviously I haven't.

In this environment, there is a Cisco 3550 as the core router.

The AP in question is a AIR-LAP1142N-A-K9 which has been configured for autonomous mode (this facility doesn't have a wifi manager), and it is sitting on a Cisco 2960 POE switch.

```
**2950 POE Switchport config for applicable ports**:

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12  
 description WiFi  
 switchport access vlan 101  
 switchport trunk native vlan 11  
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 11,102,228,700  
 switchport mode trunk  
end  

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/28  
 description LINK TO CORE  
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,11,101-106,228,700,1002-1005  
 switchport mode trunk  
end  


**Cisco 3550 Switchport config for applicable port:**  
interface GigabitEthernet0/9  
 description Link to 2960-MB-POE  
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q  
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,11,101-106,228,700,1002-1005  
 switchport mode trunk  
end
```

All other VLANS are working as designed/intended.  VLAN 700 is guest wifi, and it is pulling DHCP from 3550.  All other VLANS (except for VLAN in question) are pulling DHCP from MS Server 2008

From AP, I can ping core router IP (192.168.228.1) on VLAN, so trunking is working. I can also ping all the way to MS 2008 DHCP server, so trunking is good all the way to server

I can associate with AP (can see my MAC address in AP when run "sho dot11 associations" command) and if I set my IP address to a static IP address, the sho dot11 associations command shows my IP address

I can associate with AP and get IP address for VLAN 102

I cannot get an IP address for VLAN 228

I have tried it with forwarders set up identical as all other VLANS (to get DHCP from server), and that's not working either, so I left it at DHCP from core.

VLANs are set on cisco 3550 as the following

```
interface Vlan102
 description VLAN102
 ip address 192.168.102.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 192.168.9.98
 ip helper-address 192.168.9.103
 ip helper-address 192.168.9.85
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp

interface Vlan228
 desciption VLAN228
 ip address 192.168.228.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
!
For testing, DHCP is set up as this (on core 3550)

ip dhcp pool vlan228
   network 192.168.228.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.228.1
   dns-server 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
   lease 0 8
```

Based on everything above, to me it means that there is something wrong with my AP config. My best guess is that it has something to do with sub-interfaces or bridge groups. If that's not it, the it could be the routing on 3550, but this would be the first time in my experience that I would have to tell the core router about a vlan that was created on it. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
--------BEGIN AP CONFIGURATION----------  

Current configuration : 4949 bytes  
!  
! Last configuration change at 09:58:29 GMT-0 Wed Jul 23 2014  
! NVRAM config last updated at 09:56:11 GMT-0 Wed Jul 23 2014  
! NVRAM config last updated at 09:56:11 GMT-0 Wed Jul 23 2014  
version 15.2  
no service pad  
service timestamps debug datetime msec  
service timestamps log datetime msec  
service password-encryption  
!  
hostname AP12345  
!  
!  
logging rate-limit console 9  
no logging console  
enable secret 5 passwordhasbeenremoved  
!  
no aaa new-model  
clock timezone GMT -0 0  
clock summer-time GMT-0 recurring last Sun Mar 2:00 last Sun Oct 3:00  
no ip cef  
ip domain name myorganization.com  
ip name-server 192.168.x.x  
ip name-server 192.168.x.x  
!  
!  
!  
!  
dot11 mbssid  
dot11 syslog  
dot11 vlan-name VLANNAME1 vlan 102  
dot11 vlan-name VLANNAME2 vlan 228  
dot11 vlan-name MANAGEMENT vlan 11  
!  
dot11 ssid SSID1  
   vlan 102  
   authentication open  
   authentication key-management wpa version 2  
   mbssid guest-mode  
   wpa-psk ascii 7 passwordhasbeenremoved  
!  
dot11 ssid SSID2  
   vlan 228  
   authentication open  
   authentication key-management wpa version 2  
   mbssid guest-mode  
   wpa-psk ascii 7 passwordhasbeenremoved  
!  
!  
dot11 guest  
!  
!  
!  
username user1 privilege 15 secret 5 passwordremoved  
username user2 privilege 15 secret 5 passwordremoved  
!  
!  
bridge irb  
!  
!  
!  
interface Dot11Radio0  
 no ip address  
 no ip route-cache  
 !  
 encryption vlan 102 mode ciphers aes-ccm  
 !  
 encryption vlan 228 mode ciphers aes-ccm  
 !  
 ssid SSID1  
 !  
 ssid SSID2  
 !  
 antenna gain 0  
 speed  basic-11.0 12.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0  
 power local 8  
 channel 2412  
 station-role root  
 infrastructure-client  
!  
interface Dot11Radio0.11  
 encapsulation dot1Q 11 native  
 no ip route-cache  
 bridge-group 1  
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control  
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled  
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source  
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning  
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding  
!  
interface Dot11Radio0.102  
 encapsulation dot1Q 102  
 no ip route-cache  
 bridge-group 102  
 bridge-group 102 subscriber-loop-control  
 bridge-group 102 spanning-disabled  
 bridge-group 102 block-unknown-source  
 no bridge-group 102 source-learning  
 no bridge-group 102 unicast-flooding  
!  
interface Dot11Radio0.228  
 encapsulation dot1Q 228  
 no ip route-cache  
 bridge-group 228  
 bridge-group 228 subscriber-loop-control  
 bridge-group 228 spanning-disabled  
 bridge-group 228 block-unknown-source  
 no bridge-group 228 source-learning  
 no bridge-group 228 unicast-flooding  
!  
interface Dot11Radio1  
 no ip address  
 no ip route-cache  
 !  
 encryption vlan 102 mode ciphers aes-ccm  
 !  
 encryption vlan 228 mode ciphers aes-ccm  
 !  
 ssid SSID1  
 !  
 ssid SSID2  
 !  
 antenna gain 0  
 peakdetect  
 no dfs band block  
 channel 5745  
 station-role root  
!  
interface Dot11Radio1.11  
 encapsulation dot1Q 11 native  
 no ip route-cache  
 bridge-group 1  
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control  
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled  
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source  
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning  
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding  
!  
interface Dot11Radio1.102  
 encapsulation dot1Q 102  
 no ip route-cache  
 bridge-group 102  
 bridge-group 102 subscriber-loop-control  
 bridge-group 102 spanning-disabled  
 bridge-group 102 block-unknown-source  
 no bridge-group 102 source-learning  
 no bridge-group 102 unicast-flooding  
!  
interface Dot11Radio1.228  
 encapsulation dot1Q 228  
 no ip route-cache  
 bridge-group 228  
 bridge-group 228 subscriber-loop-control  
 bridge-group 228 spanning-disabled  
 bridge-group 228 block-unknown-source  
 no bridge-group 228 source-learning  
 no bridge-group 228 unicast-flooding  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet0  
 no ip address  
 no ip route-cache  
 duplex auto  
 speed auto  
 bridge-group 1  
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled  
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet0.11  
 encapsulation dot1Q 11  
 no ip route-cache  
 bridge-group 11  
 bridge-group 11 spanning-disabled  
 no bridge-group 11 source-learning  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet0.102  
 encapsulation dot1Q 102  
 no ip route-cache  
 no cdp enable  
 bridge-group 102  
 bridge-group 102 spanning-disabled  
 no bridge-group 102 source-learning  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet0.228  
 encapsulation dot1Q 228  
 no ip route-cache  
 no cdp enable  
 bridge-group 228  
 bridge-group 228 spanning-disabled  
 no bridge-group 228 source-learning  
!  
interface BVI1  
 ip address 192.168.9.133 255.255.255.0  
 no ip route-cache  
 ipv6 address dhcp  
 ipv6 address autoconfig  
 ipv6 enable  
!  
ip default-gateway 192.168.9.1  
ip forward-protocol nd  
no ip http server  
no ip http secure-server  
ip http help-path http://www.cisco.com/warp/public/779/smbiz/prodconfig/help/eag  
!  
!  
bridge 1 route ip  
!  
!  
!  
line con 0  
 privilege level 15  
line vty 0 4  
 login local  
 transport input ssh  
line vty 5 15  
 login  
 transport input ssh  
!  

sntp server 165.193.126.229  
sntp server 216.171.112.36  
sntp server 206.246.122.250  
end  

------------------END AP CONFIGURATION---------------
```

Comment: For anyone who sees this question, it has been solved...in my desire to get this implemented quickly, I forgot to set up the VLAN on the POE switch...could ping to core, so I thought it was something to do with the AP.  Once I added the correct vlan on the poe switch, everything worked perfectly. Turned off DHCP on the core 3550, added the forwarders to the VLAN 228 for the MS Server, and BAM!

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to set up the correct vlan on the POE switch...see previous comment for more detail. This is resolved with me feeling foolish.